# Authentication failure spring-amqp timeout

Tags: authentication, timeout, spring-amqp

My consumer worked fine for about one week, then the consumer thread died and logged the below error:

> It seems the Authentication failure is caused by
>   BufferedInputStream.read timeout, and I want to know if there is a way
>   to treat the Authentication failure as a non-fatal and do not kill the
>   consumer thread. and I think the timeout issue is just caused by
>   network issue not the Authentication failure, since this consumer
>   already worked for one week.

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.FatalListenerStartupException: Authentication failure
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:460)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1171)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpAuthenticationException: com.rabbitmq.client.PossibleAuthenticationFailureException: Possibly caused by authentication failure
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:61)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:296)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:85)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:135)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:71)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:456)
... 2 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.PossibleAuthenticationFailureException: Possibly caused by authentication failure
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:341)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:824)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:736)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:283)
... 7 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrExcept‌​ion.java:66) at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibl‌​eGetValue(BlockingVa‌​lueOrException.java:‌​36) at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.‌​getReply(AMQChannel.‌​java:366) at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.ja‌​va:233) at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.rpc(AMQChannel.java:211) at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.j‌​ava:326)
```

Comment: Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:366)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:233)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.rpc(AMQChannel.java:211)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:326)

Comment: Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:288)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:94)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:138)

Comment: first time to ask question here, and always got Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar ico. so i add some comments to post my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target code looks like:

```
} catch (ShutdownSignalException e) {
...
   throw new PossibleAuthenticationFailureException(e);
}
```

So, indeed, it isn't necessary that the issue with the connection is about authentication.

There is just `ShutdownSignalException` by the `Connection timed out` reason.

So, you should just try to increase connection timeout, which is `60000` by default.

But that is likely there is some problem with resources on the broker since we just can't connect.

We can't treat this kind of errors (`ShutdownSignalException`) as non-fatal, since your problem happens exactly on the `start()`.

**EDIT**

In case of fatal failure the container emits `ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent`:http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#consumer-events. You can handle it and restart the container on purpose.

Comment: but this error not happened at i start the application, it happened at the project running for one week online, it worked fine before the error. and what kind of timeout i should set? reply, receive or connection timeout? and if i set to -1,it will never timeout, am i right? and the timeout will affect the java.io.BufferedInputStream.read method？ since i saw the error is caused by it.

Comment: Connection timeout because you can't connection to the Broker. The `BufferedInputStream.read` is just low-level how connection waits for reply from the socket server. As I said: looks like there is a leakage of resources on the Broker. So, it just can't open a new connection for you after the week. Maybe you don't close old connection somewhere... Or your target consumer is blocked permanently that Listener Container is forced to start new and new connection to catch up messages from the queue...

Comment: thanks for your reply! so increase the timeout is not the  way to solve my problem, i should find the reason why mq sever leak the resource. and i only use sping amqp consume to connect to that sever, i should to close some connection in my code? and i have anther consumer sever connect to that sever in different vhost, it works fine and doesn't encouter timeout issue.

Comment: Maybe that consumer doesn't have `considerAddingAConsumer();` functionality and just lives on a single connection?..

Comment: If a fatal happened in spring amqp and the consumer is killed, do i have a simple way to restart the consumer?

Comment: Another way, I need to add a monitor to the amqp thread, when it dies, I should start it manually in the monitor thread?

Comment: Please, look into and EDIT in  my answer.